# Node Js json file read

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to read the "name" and "tel" from data.json(json file) by using app.js(node js file)

---

This is data.json file

```
{
 "result": {
  "site": {
   "list": [
    {
     "name": "imready",
     "tel": "0123456789"
    },
    {
     "name": "hihello",
     "tel": "9876543210"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

---

This is the app.js file:

```
fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
console.log(data)});
```

I want to get: "name": "imready", "tel": "0123456789","name": "hihello", "tel": "9876543210".

How can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse(data)` inside your `fs.readFile()` callback. When reading your JSON from the file, you're just reading it as plain text, you need to explicitly generate the JS Object from the contents of `data` using `JSON.parse()`.

```
fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  var json = JSON.parse(data);

  // print { name: 'imready', tel: '0123456789' }
  console.log(json.list[0]);

  // print { name: 'hihello', tel: '9876543210' }
  console.log(json.list[1]);
});
```

Comment: *"...you're just reading it as plain text and not as JSON..."* JSON *is* plain text. He's reading it as JSON and needs to convert it to native JS objects.

Comment: @squint updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just require the `json` file and read from it as an object:

```
var obj = require('./data.json');
// now you can do:
console.log(obj.result.site.list[0].name) // => imready
```